# How do I recognize strings that do not end with a slash character ('/') using a regex?

Tags: regex

How can i match a string that does not finish with `/` . I know I can do that `/\/$/` and it will match if string does finish with `/`, but how can I test to see if it doesn't?

Comment: You could also just test whether the last character of the string is a slash or not... with normal string manipulation functions. In JavaScript: `str.charAt(str.length-1) !== '/'`.

Comment: @Nikolay: Please reward the people who have helped you in the past and accept answers to your older questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a negative [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/[^\/]$/
```

This however requires that the string contains at least one character. If you also want to allow the empty string you can use an alternation:

```
/[^\/]$|^$/
```

A different approach is to use a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but note that many popular regular expression engines do not support lookbehinds:

```
/(?<!\/)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say "not character" by doing `[^...]`. In this case, you can say "not backslash by doing": `/[^\/]$/`

Answer (score 0):

`[^\/]$`

`^` will negate any character class expression.

Comment: I'd love to see these negotiations :)

Comment: Negate, probably? @TimPietzcker :)